# How to access the non-primary DataSource in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the most simple spring boot program:
The main:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    private AdapterFixRepository adapterFixRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        System.out.println("Id 736: " + adapterFixRepository.getById(736L));
    }   
}
```

The entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class AdapterFix {    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;
    private String senderCompId;
}
```

The DAO:

```
public interface AdapterFixRepository extends CrudRepository<AdapterFix, Long> {
    String SELECT_ADAPTER_FIX_BY_ID        =    " SELECT fix.*, adp.*, stm.* " +
                                                " FROM  `tr-dev`.adapter_fix AS fix " +
                                                " INNER JOIN `tr-dev`.adapter AS adp ON fix.ID = adp.ID " +
                                                " INNER JOIN `tr-dev`.stream_types AS stm ON stm.ID = fix.STREAM_TYPES_ID " +
                                                " WHERE fix.ID = :id";

    AdapterFix findById(@Param("id") Long id);

    @Query(value = SELECT_ADAPTER_FIX_BY_ID, nativeQuery = true)
    AdapterFix getById(@Param("id") Long id);
}
```

And also in application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tr-dev?autoReconnect=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=***
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

It all worked good.
I then tried to add another DB. I deleted my application.properties, and added this config file:

```
@Configuration
@Qualifier("second.spring.datasource")
public class DataSourceConfig {
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "first.spring.datasource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "first.spring.datasource")
    @Qualifier("first.spring.datasource")
    public DataSource firstDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().url("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tr-dev?autoReconnect=true").username("root").password("***").
                driverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").build();
    }


    @Bean(name = "second.spring.datasource")
    @Qualifier("second.spring.datasource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "second.spring.datasource")
    public DataSource secondDataSource() {          
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().url("jdbc:mysql://10.2.5.63:3306/tr-dev?autoReconnect=true").username("root").password("***").
                driverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").build();
    }
}
```

It selected from my first datasource. I tried adding     @Qualifier("second.spring.datasource") all around, didn't help. I tried adding the qualifier in the method in the DAO, didn't help. I tried adding the qualifier in the main class, the Autowired and the run method - didn't help. It also didn't help when I added "second.spring.datasource" on application.properties.

What am I doing wrong? What else should I do? I can see other codes that access multiple DB's, but they are way too complicated, with many Bean and other hibernate specific properties - not a simple spring boot definition. Must I move to hibernate and use many bean and transaction managers?

Comment: Do you use Spring Data JPA?

Comment: Yes, in the @Query in the DAO.

Comment: You can assign different data sources by using different configurations with `@EnableJpaRepositories`. There was an [article](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases) quite recently that might help you.

Comment: Again this solutin is includes many Bean(s), Hibernate statements, LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean, PlatformTransactionManager and more. My spring class is very basic. Isn't there a basic way to do this? Doesn't sound so difficult.

Comment: Repositories don't use data sources, entity managers do. And transaction managers use entity managers. So you need two sets of at least three different beans. The example *is* very basic. You can simply copy most of the configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you need to tell spring which entities belong to which database. The following code assumes Spring Boot 2.0. You also need to config which repository belongs to which config. For the repositories this is dones through the `@EnableJpaRepositories` while the entity packages are specified inside the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`.

Primary database config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = {"primary.repository.package"}
)
public class JpaPrimaryConfig {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties primaryDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource")
    public DataSource configurePrimaryDataSource() {
        return primaryDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(configurePrimaryDataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("primary.entity.package");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("primaryPersistenceUnit");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = {"transactionManager", "primaryTransactionManager"})
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());

        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

Secondary database config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "secondaryEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "secondaryTransactionManager",
        basePackages = {"secondary.repository.package"}
)
public class JpaSecondaryConfig {


    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("datasource.secondary")
    public DataSourceProperties secondaryDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "secondaryDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.secondary")
    public DataSource configureSecondaryDataSource() {
        return secondaryDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "secondaryEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(configureSecondaryDataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("secondary.entity.package");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("secondaryPersistenceUnit");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean(name = "secondaryTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());

        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

You can then configure both datasources as usual using the application properties. The primary database config is located under the default `datasource.*` path and the secondary config is located at `datasource.secondary.*`

Comment: How can I choose from where to select?

Comment: What do you mean by "where to select"? The mapping between the repository and the database config is done through the `@EnableJpaRepositories` Attribute. You need to have separate packages for the entities of the first db and the second db. The same applies for the repositories.

Comment: I have been struggling to implement this. I am getting Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type. Anyone has successfully implemented this ?